# How to use constructor objects in another state using flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am creating this shopping app , the home page displays pictures and some data from firestore firebase as a gridView. [THIS IS THE SCREEN OF THIS PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJfyN.jpg)

Once the user click on one of the images in this page the app will show him another page contains more details about the product with Hero animation.
[THIS IS THE SECOND PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tklUR.jpg)
The second page is a stateless widget and it takes some parameters

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GridView.builder(

  ........

  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
    String image = documents[index].data['image'].toString();
    String ti = documents[index].data['title'].toString();
    String prix = documents[index].data['price'].toString();
    String desc = documents[index].data['description'].toString();
    String categ = documents[index].data['category'].toString();
    return new Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius:
      new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(15.0)),
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
           context,
           new MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) =>
           new FullScreenImagePage(image,ti,prix,desc,categ)));
        },
        child: new Hero(
          tag: image,
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0)),
              new FadeInImage(
                image: new NetworkImage(image),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                placeholder: new AssetImage("assets/ic.png"),
              ),
              new Text(ti, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, height: 1.0),),
              new Text('prix: $prix MAD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.0),),
            ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
```

Then I receive the parameters in this class

```
class FullScreenImagePage extends StatelessWidget {
  String imgPath ,title,price,desc,categ;
  FullScreenImagePage(this.imgPath,this.title,this.price,this.desc,this.categ);

...... 

 Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   child: Hero(
     tag: imgPath,
     child: Material(
       elevation: 20.0,
       shadowColor: Colors.black26,
       child: Image(
         image: NetworkImage(imgPath),
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
       ),
     ),
   ),
 ),
```

The problem that I have is that I wanna change the stateless widget of FullScreenImagePage to stateful with keeping the same variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using IntelliJ
you can change you stateless widget into a stateful one using ***alt+enter***

- go to the class name{{FullScreenImagePage}
- press alt + Enter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the stateless widget to stateful widget either manually or by using the shortcut(quick fix). Then access your variable in the state subclass using widget.variable_name